# Send API request from pickerview selection

Tags: ios, swift, swift4

I'm new to swift and creating my first app atm.

I have a pickerview which i fill from api data. It works.

Now i want to make another call to the api with the selected value of the first pickerview and fill the data which I receive into another pickerview.

The problem I get: it fills in the same data(from the first request) into the second pickerview.

Here is the code I use:

```
struct Job: Decodable{
    let beruf_name: String
    let beruf_id: String
}
struct Class: Decodable{
    let klassen_id: String
    let klassen_longname: String
}

class ViewController: UIViewController, 
UIPickerViewDelegate,UIPickerViewDataSource {


@IBOutlet weak var classPicker: UIPickerView!
@IBOutlet weak var pickerview: UIPickerView!
@IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!

var jobs = [Job]()
var classes = [Class]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    pickerview.delegate = self
    pickerview.dataSource = self
    classPicker.delegate = self
    classPicker.dataSource = self



    let url = URL(string: "http://home.gibm.ch/interfaces/133/berufe.php")

    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) { (data, response, err) in
        if err == nil {
            do{
                try self.jobs = JSONDecoder().decode([Job].self, from: data!)
            }catch{
                print("Parse error")
            }
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.pickerview.reloadComponent(0)
            }
        }
    }.resume()
}

//pickerview methods

func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
    return 1;
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
    return jobs.count
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
    return jobs[row].beruf_name
}


//delegate method

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
    let selectedJob = jobs[row].beruf_id
    label.text = selectedJob

    let class_url = URL(string: "http://home.gibm.ch/interfaces/133/klassen.php?beruf_id="+selectedJob)

    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: class_url!) { (data, response, err) in
        if err == nil {
            do{
                try self.classes = JSONDecoder().decode([Class].self, from: data!)
                print(self.classes)
            }catch{
                print("Parse error")
            }
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.classPicker.reloadComponent(0)
            }
        }
    }.resume()
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've set `ViewController` as the data source for both `pickerView` and `classPicker`. This is fine but currently you are only returning data relevant to `pickerView` so `classPicker` is populated with the same data as `pickerView`. You will need to say something like:

```
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
    if pickerView === self.pickerView {
        return jobs.count
    }
    else {
        return classes.count
    }

}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
    if pickerView === self.pickerView {
        return jobs[row].beruf_name
    }
    else {
        return classes[row].klasse_longname
    }
}
```

You will likely want to do the same for your delegate method `func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int)`

Additionally, when you make the API call after selecting the first item you will get a "parse error" this is because the API is returning objects like:

> {"klasse_id":"2898290","klasse_name":"BBM 16-18 A","klasse_longname":"Berufsmatura II BBM 16-18 A"}

"klasse" not "klassen" so you will need to update your struct:

```
struct Class: Decodable{
    let klasse_id: String
    let klasse_name: String
    let klasse_longname: String
}
```